# Oracle - build dimension from a file based data source

Tags: oracle, csv, data-warehouse, dimensions, dimensional-modeling

I'm trying to build a star schema in Oracle 12c. In my case my data source is not a relational database but a single excel/csv file which is populated via a google form, which means I don't have any sort of reference from a source system such as auto incremental keys/ids. Now what would be the best approach to build a star schema given this condition?

File row sample:

```
<submitted timestamp>,<submitted by user>,<region>,<country>,<branch>,<branch location>,<branch area>,<branch type>,<branch name>,<branch private? yes/no value>,<the following would be all "fact" values (measurements),...,...,...
```

In case i wanted to build a "branch" dimension, how would I handle updates/inserts after the first load into the dimension table?

**Thought solution so far:**

I had thought of making a concatenated string "key" with the branch values, which would make it unique (underscore would be the "glue" to concatenate the values), eg:

```
<region>_<country>_<branch>_<branch location> as branch_key
```

I would insert all the distinct branches into a staging table, including they branch_key column for each one of them, then when trying to load into the dimension I could compare which key does not exists yet in my dimension table and then insert it. As for updates, I'm a bit stuck on how to handle that, I had thought of having another file mapping which branches are active having a expiration date column. Basically trying to simulate what I could do having the data in a database instead of CSV files.

This is all I can think of so far, do you have any other recommendations/ideas on how to implement this? Take on consideration that the data source cannot as in I **have to** read these csv files, since data is not stored anywhere else.

Thank you.